# IllegalStateException for MediaPlayer.prepareAsync

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

```
05-19 11:52:51.622: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1291): prepareAsync called in state 8
05-19 11:52:51.622: WARN/System.err(1291): java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

```
try {
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(
            Main.this,
            Uri.parse("http://codejanitor.us/good.mp3"));
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    try {
        mp.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} finally {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}
```

ALTERNATELY

If I do:

```
try {
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(
            AmazonClipActivity.this,
            Uri.parse("http://codejanitor.us/good.mp3"));
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
} finally {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}
```

I get:

```
05-19 12:22:57.472: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1635): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
05-19 12:22:57.472: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(68): setDataSource('http://codejanitor.us/good.mp3')
05-19 12:22:57.482: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(68): connect to codejanitor.us:80/good.mp3 @0
05-19 12:23:00.632: INFO/NuCachedSource2(68): ERROR_END_OF_STREAM
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

[`mp = MediaPlayer.create(...);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%20int)) is already preparing the MediaPlayer returned, so you cannot call `prepare` (or its variants) again (and there is no need for onPreparedListener as well).

Comment: I updated my question with an alternate code path that also fails, would appreciate your input

Comment: Please refer to this link: http://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod/issues/detail?id=1023

Comment: @BinyaminSharet your link is broken.

Comment: This answer might help folks looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53390067/826946

Answer (score 11):

**"prepareAsync called in state 8"** means the Mediaplayer is already prepared.

are you calling `mp.prepare();` in your code?

Comment: I updated my question with an alternate code path that also fails, would appreciate your input

Answer (score 8):

Your updated question:

1. Check whether you have INTERNET permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. Check whether you have some data connection enabled, as you want to stream from the internet
3. What do you mean with "this solution also fails"? Does it throw an IllegalStateException? From what I see, it just won't do anything at all, because you register your OnPreparedListener after the MediaPlayer object has prepared itself, causing the `onPrepared()` method never to be called.

A better approach would be to write:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();  
mp.setDataSource("http://.../movie.mp4");  
mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);  
mp.prepareAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Base Problem lies on calling methods of `MediaPlayer` at "not allowed states". State Diagram is [shown here](https://developer.android.com/images/mediaplayer_state_diagram.gif). For example, calling `start()` method without **preparing** the media file is not allowed and will throw Exception.

Since `MediaPlayer` does not expose `getState()` method, you should track states externally. Sample implementation can be [found here](https://gist.github.com/jemshit/3fd38d3ba04556c99bd7d953f5c056f7).

Answer (score 0):

I use below code to play sound files for http.

```
BackgroundSound mBackgroundSound = new BackgroundSound();

public void onSoundRequested(final Uri uri) {
    mBackgroundSound = new BackgroundSound();
    mBackgroundSound.execute(new SoundModel(dicId, uri));
}

public class BackgroundSound extends AsyncTask<SoundModel, Void, Void> {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(SoundModel... params) {
        SoundModel model = params[0];
        final Uri uri = model.getUri();

        if (uri == null || uri == Uri.EMPTY) return null;
        if (mediaPlayer != null) mediaPlayer.stop();

        try {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(VocabularyActivity.this, uri);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do nothing.
        }
        if (mediaPlayer == null) return null;

        mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.start();
        return null;
    }
}
```

It shows warnimg `W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open https://something.com/test.mp3: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://something.com/test.mp3` but works fine.